# Wonderflux Framework Static Homepage

Tags: customization, homepage, frontpage, static-website

I recently started wp development and am trying to make a website on the Wonderflux framework.

Currently, I set the homepage as a static page from the WP admin dashboard. Now I am currently editing said page inside wp.

[image: wp edit]

Is this the correct way to do this? Is there a way to simply redirect to `custom-home.php` on page load? Where that file would load the header, page content and the footer.

I am going to be having multiple pages with each their own looks so I think this should be accomplished using functions.php in my child theme but I'm not sure where to start. I just want WP to mainly handle pages with posts/blog content.

I apologize if I sound a bit scattered, I don't think using a framework for my first WP project was a good idea. I'm used to bootstrap and was looking for a similar environment to build a responsive website. I feel like the only way I can properly learn everything is to build a theme from the ground up using the codex, but I don't have that much time unfortunately.

Any guidance would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [WordPress Template Hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) to see how to have different looks for different pages. The template for the front page, for instance, should be named `front-page.php`. If you follow the naming convention for templates, you don't need to do anything in `functions.php`

Comment: Thanks for the response! So if I want a custom template for my about page, I would create `about.php` and an about page in WP and then use `is_page( ‘about’ )` to call `get_template_part("about")` in `functions.php` ?

Comment: No. You create a template called `page-about.php`. If the slug of your page is 'about' everything else will be done automatically.

Comment: Just study the picture in the link I gave carefully and you will know how to name a template in order for WP to pick everything up by itself.

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually the author of Wonderflux ;) It does require some technical knowledge to work with it, but essentially it does a-lot of stuff the 'WordPress way' ;)

The guidance given is correct - however, you need to duplicate page.php into your child theme to retain all of the Wonderflux theme hooks (which is pretty standard when it comes to theme frameworks).

Alternatively, an easier way to use Wonderflux like this is the smart template part system - so create loop-content-home.php or loop-content-page.php in your child theme ;) There is full documentation on this in the readme.md file included with Wonderflux.